# How to write event handler for page/node loading in aem cq5

Tags: aem

I want to write an aem event handler for page loading. I know how to implement event handler for node is added & deleted. But now I need to get an event when the node or page is loading. How can I implement this?

Comment: What's the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: We are having one check box in one of the tab of every aem page properties. Now we are adding an other check box under this existing check box there is some dependency on this existing check box means already few existing pages having that check box values as true or checked we need to set by default true for this new check box which we are trying to adding now. In an other case any existing pages having existing or old check box values are false we need to remove this dependency logic for new check box.